How can I sed two curly braces on two lines and add a coma between them on a Mac?
I'm trying to parse some JSON and am running into an issue with parsing. My objects are:
{ 
  "foo" : "bar"
}
{
  "spam" : "ham"
}

I want to change this in a shell script to:
{ 
  "foo" : "bar"
},
{
  "spam" : "ham"
}

I've tried:
sed 's/}\n{/},\n{/g' file.json > file.json.tmp
and solutions like Replace curly braces separated by a newline with sed But without any progress. Any clue what I am missing here?

Usually, tools that handle streams of objects can understand the first example, but not the second. A tool expecting a single JSON value won't accept either.

jq -s ., however, will turn the first example into a valid array containing the two objects.

Interesting point! Sorry for being so new to this, but what is a good way yo handle streams of objects in python?

Consider reformatting to JSON Lines format using jq -c; then Python need only read a single line at a time and decode each separately. I don't have any advice for parsing arbitrarily serialized JSON streams in Python.

Using GNU sed for -z to read the whole input into memory at once as a single multi-line record:
$ sed -z 's/}\n{/},\n{/g' file
{
  "foo" : "bar"
},
{
  "spam" : "ham"
}

or doing the same using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:
$ awk '{r=(NR>1 ? r RS : "") $0} END{$0=r; gsub(/}\n\{/,"},\n{"); print}' file
{
  "foo" : "bar"
},
{
  "spam" : "ham"
}

The default sed on MacOS is BSD, not GNU, so the above sed command won't work unless you install GNU sed. The awk command will work on MacOS or anywhere else.
Your sed command in the question couldn't find \n in the string it's working on because sed works on 1 \n-separated string at a time by default and so the string it's working on can't contain \n as it's separated from the previous and next strings by \n.

Using perl is easier :
perl -0777 -pe 's/}\n\{/},\n{/g' file.json > file.json.tmp

Or if you have gnu-sed :
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/}\n[{]/},\n{/g' file.json > file.json.tmp


This seems to work on my command line. In a shell script though, I get issues with escaping the \n and the {.

Is the perl script not working ? Can you post error message ?

If I escape every single \ in the perl command, I get line 7: {/},: No such file or directory.

I tested with bash and zsh scripting, the perl command should work unchanged (meaning you don't need to do any more escaping).

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 'N;s/}\n{/},\n{/;P;D' file

Open a two line window throughout the length of the file and if the last character of the first line is } and the first character of the next line is {, insert a , before the newline.
